# Optimal way of cycling through 1000's of values

Tags: php, math, mathematical-optimization

I need to find the value of x where the variance of two results (which take x into account) is the closest to 0. The problem is, the only way to do this is to cycle through all possible values of x. The equation uses currency, so I have to check in increments of 1 cent.

This might make it easier:

```
$previous_var = null;
$high_amount = 50;

for ($i = 0.01; $i <= $high_amount; $i += 0.01) {
    $val1 = find_out_1($i);
    $val2 = find_out_2();

    $var = variance($val1, $val2);

    if ($previous_var == null) {
        $previous_var = $var;
    }

    // If this variance is larger, it means the previous one was the closest to 
    // 0 as the variance has now started increasing
    if ($var > $previous_var) {
        $l_s -= 0.01;
        break;
    }
}

$optimal_monetary_value = $i;
```

I feel like there is a mathematical formula that would make the "cycling through every cent" more optimal? It works fine for small values, but if you start using 1000's as the $high_amount it takes quite a few seconds to calculate.

Comment: while reading this, i realized that i should improve my math... but can you give examples of Output? ;D

Comment: Show me the output so I would understand it more

Comment: Could you be more clear about the math problem? With all your functions (`find_out_1`, `find_out_2`, `variance`) being anonymous I don't think we could possibly suggest a better solution other than brute force.

Comment: What do you call the variance here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment in your code, it sounds like you want something similar to bisection search, but a little bit different:

```
function calculate_variance($i) {
  $val1 = find_out_1($i);
  $val2 = find_out_2();

  return variance($val1, $val2);
}

function search($lo, $loVar, $hi, $hiVar) {
  // find the midpoint between the hi and lo values
  $mid = round($lo + ($hi - $lo) / 2, 2);
  if ($mid == $hi || $mid == $lo) {
    // we have converged, so pick the better value and be done
    return ($hiVar > $loVar) ? $lo : $hi;
  }
  $midVar = calculate_variance($mid);
  if ($midVar >= $loVar) {
    // the optimal point must be in the lower interval
    return search($lo, $loVar, $mid, $midVar);
  } elseif ($midVar >= $hiVar) {
    // the optimal point must be in the higher interval
    return search($mid, $midVar, $hi, $hiVar);
  } else {
    // we don't know where the optimal point is for sure, so check
    // the lower interval first
    $loBest = search($lo, $loVar, $mid, $midVar);
    if ($loBest == $mid) {
      // we can't be sure this is the best answer, so check the hi
      // interval to be sure
      return search($mid, $midVar, $hi, $hiVar);
    } else {
      // we know this is the best answer
      return $loBest;
    }
  }
}

$optimal_monetary_value = search(0.01, calculate_variance(0.01), 50.0, calculate_variance(50.0));
```

This assumes that the variance is monotonically increasing when moving away from the optimal point.  In other words, if the optimal value is `O`, then for all `X < Y < O`, `calculate_variance(X) >= calculate_variance(Y) >= calculate_variance(O)` (and the same with all `>` and `<` flipped).  The comment in your code and the way have you have it written make it seem like this is true.  If this isn't true, then you can't really do much better than what you have.

Be aware that this is not as good as bisection search.  There are some pathological inputs that will make it take linear time instead of logarithmic time (e.g., if the variance is the same for all values).  If you can improve the requirement that `calculate_variance(X) >= calculate_variance(Y) >= calculate_variance(O)` to be `calculate_variance(X) > calculate_variance(Y) > calculate_variance(O)`, you can improve this to be logarithmic in all cases by checking to see how the variance for `$mid` compares the the variance for `$mid + 0.01` and using that to decide which interval to check.

Also, you may want to be careful about doing math with currency.  You probably either want to use integers (i.e., do all math in cents instead of dollars) or use exact precision numbers.

Comment: This procedure is indeed not perfect as there are configurations such that you don't know which subinterval to choose. When you consider four points at a time instead of three, this issue is solved. On every iteration, you reject one interval among three. The optimal interval size reduction strategy is achieved by the Golden/Fibonacci methods. This is the proper generalization of bisection.

Comment: Thanks, @Austin - implementing your methods above have made a considerable difference. When using amount 5000, my old method took 10.18 seconds to calculate. After implementing your modified bisectional search, this has gone down to 465 ms.

Comment: @ChimeraTheory: you must verify that the minimum is unique or you can get wrong results.

Comment: @Austin: the minimum will always be 0.01 - is this what you're referring to? I've done a few calculations and so far it's matched the Excel spreadsheet (which uses Solver to come to the same conclusion) 100%.

Comment: +1 Well thought. Although logically your assumption may not be true (based on limited information OP provided), in real world it very likely is.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ah yeah you are right, if you used multiple intervals, you could get better guarantees.  I'll update the code if I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

If you known nothing at all about the behavior of the objective function, there is no other way than trying all possible values.

On the opposite if you have a guarantee that the minimum is unique, the Golden section method will converge very quickly. This is a variant of the Fibonacci search, which is known to be optimal (require the minimum number of function evaluations).

Your function may have different properties which call for other algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Why not implementing **binary search** ?

```
<?php
$high_amount    = 50;
// computed val2 is placed outside the loop
// no need te recalculate it each time
$val2           = find_out_2();
$previous_var   = variance(find_out_1(0.01), $val2);

$start              = 0;
$end                = $high_amount * 100;
$closest_variance   = NULL;
while ($start <= $end) {
    $section    = intval(($start + $end)/2);
    $cursor     = $section / 100;
    $val1       = find_out_1($cursor);
    $variance   = variance($val1, $val2);

    if ($variance <= $previous_var) {
        $start = $section;
    }
    else {
        $closest_variance   = $cursor;
        $end                = $section;
    }
}

if (!is_null($closest_variance)) {
    $closest_variance -= 0.01;
}
```